# Icons not appearing next to custom categories in Main Menu

Tags: icons, cinnamon

Just installed LM 17 Qiana Cinnamon. Installing applications and have added some custom menus. These appear as in the `~/.local/share/desktop-directories` folder and look like:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Comment=
Type=Directory
Name=GIS
Icon=~/.local/share/icons/custom/applications-geography.svg
```

However, the icon does not appear in the menu. Notice two application categories in the menu that have no icon next to them:

[image]

The path is fine, because when I add the menu in alacarte, the icon displays in the properties dialog:

[image]

Any thoughts?

Comment: I rejected your flag because Linux Mint questions are [off topic](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/684/85695) on [ubuntu.se] so the migration was quite correct.

Comment: Which version of cinnamon is this and what do you have to do after crating the .desktop file to make it appear? I tried what you describe on Cinnamon 2.0.14 and there were no changes to the menu. Could you explain how to reproduce this so I can play with it and try to answer? One possibility is that `~` is not being expanded, try using the whole path instead: `Icon=/home/username/.local/share/icons/custom/applications-geography.svg`.

Comment: Using Cinnamon 2.2.16. I am editing it via GUI using cinnamon-menu-editor (Preferences→Cinnamon Menu Editor). The GUI is writing the full path, not using ~.

Comment: I've tried several changes, including copying the files the /usr/share/icons directory, making sure that file permissions are set to read-only, etc. I looked for some info on the appropriate format for *.directory files and found a guide at gnome.org which says "Icon: Specifies the filename of an icon that represents the menu. Does not specify the path to the filename, or the filename extension." But cinnamon-menu-editor is writing the whol path. Not sure how else it could find the icon though. https://people.gnome.org/~shaunm/admin-guide/menustructure-14.html

Comment: Same problem. I even see it in menu editor, but don't see in menu. Tried to change folder, perms, even size (most of them are 48x48) though it's rather strange for scalable graphics